# XCode ios4 UIWebView Code Problem

Tags: xcode, uiwebview, ios4

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [webView loadRequest:(NSURLRequest) requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/ca/album/zirka-live/id352921457"]];]; 

}
```

Comment: What's the question? And highlight all three lines and then hit the code button.

Answer (score 2):

```
[webView loadRequest:(NSURLRequest) requestWithURL:[NSURL
    URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/..."]];];
```

should be

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL
    URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/..."]]];
```

that is

```
 (NSURLRequest) => [NSURLRequest
 ];]; => ]];
```