# iOS 5 - app runs fine, iOS 4 - hangs on [UIWebView alloc]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am testing backward compatibility of an app before submitting it to the app store.

iOS 5 devices run the app great, but now I'm testing on an old iPod touch with iOS 4.2.1.

**What Goes Wrong:**

At one point (always the same point), the app just hangs - it doesn't crash, just freezes so I'm thinking it's not a lack of memory causing it.

No errors are displayed, however following the code by setting breakpoints results in this line:

```
myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
```

running but never finishing.

**So:**

What might be going wrong, what can I do to further get more info/logs about what may be happening? Any ideas are much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Dunno; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305396/xcode-ios4-uiwebview-code-problem

Comment: a shot in the dark: could it be that the problem is not in iOS 4.2.1 itself but that this device does not have a WiFi connection and that you're handling off-line errors incorrectly.

Comment: @rokjarc - thanks, If I take the line of code out it runs fine though so it must be that. I shoulda put that in my question sorry!

Comment: Another option: are you using any 'weak' references and ARC - for delegates maybe? Not sure but i think they can only be compiled correctly for iOS 5.

Comment: @rokjarc and the webview isn't getting online content. Just using it as a text field :)

Comment: @rokjarc Ahh great point! Yes I'm using ARC but just checked and I can't find any weak references.

Comment: You say the problem goes away if you comment out this line. Then problem probably lies in some other piece of code that isn't executed if you remov this line. Maybe some UIWebViewDelegate methods? Or some code block that only runs after `if (mywebview) {...}`. Then i'm out of ideas - hope you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't have duplicate entries like instance variable and property for "_myWebView" and "myWebView". Try to use _myWebView.

Try to remove assignment statement and see if it works then problem is duplicating ivar and property.